# Input not registering in OnCollisonEnter2D,OnCollisionExit2D and OnCollisionStay2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I am trying to get input when my player collides with another object. But the problem is i am not getting any input. I am getting inputs in update function but not in OnCollisonEnter2D,OnCollisionExit2D and OnCollisionStay2D.
Here is my script

public class PlayerInteractions : MonoBehaviour {

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject chestHelperMessage;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Chest")) {
        chestHelperMessage.SetActive(true);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
            Debug.Log("You got a weapon");
        }
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Chest")) {
        chestHelperMessage.SetActive(false);
    }
}

private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Chest")) {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
            Debug.Log("Chest opened");
        }
    }
}
```

}

none of the function is giving inputs.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

for `OnCollisonEnter2D` and `OnCollisionExit` it is pretty unlikely that you press the key down exactly in the very same frame where the collision event happens.

Also for `OnCollisionStay2D` the call happens together with `FixedUpdate`, the physics routine. They are not happening every frame so it can happen that also here you miss the one or other input.

In general you should get user input in `Update` and do e.g.

```
// In case you need the chest reference itself
private GameObject currentChest;

IEnumerator CheckInputRoutine()
{
    if (chestHelperMessage.activeSelf && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    // Or also
    //if(currentChest && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) 
    {
        Debug.Log("You got a weapon");
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) 
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Chest")) 
    {
        chestHelperMessage.SetActive(true);  
        currentChest = collision.gameObject;

        StartCorouine (CheckInputRoutine());  
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) 
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Chest")) 
    {
        chestHelperMessage.SetActive(false);
        currentChest = null;
        StopAllCoroutines ();
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you want him to have a useless check in the update for the entire game while he might never even trigger that event during that play session. A better way would be for him to put OnCollisionEnter/Exit events on a script directly on the chest , detect if the player has collided and only then check if the key is pressed (of course using Update or creating a special event)

Comment: @RobertStan well depends how often this is expected to happen. You can either check this for all chests in a single controller on the player or let each chest check for collision with the player .. One update call more or less is really not a huge issue tbh .. you want to start optimizing in other places. I told OP what the issue is with the current approach and provide one alternative solution of possibly hundred other and probably even better ways to do so ... post an answer if you one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RoberStan, the code given by you is not working for my game, but some changes made it work.

Here is the new code

```
// text on the screen to help the player which key to press to pick up the item
[SerializeField] private GameObject chestHelperMessage;

private GameObject currentChest;

private void CheckInput() {

    // checking that if the helperMessage is active and getting key inputs
    if (chestHelperMessage.activeSelf && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
        Debug.Log("You got a weapon");
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Chest")) {
        chestHelperMessage.SetActive(true);
        currentChest = collision.gameObject;
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Chest")) {
        chestHelperMessage.SetActive(false);
        currentChest = null;
    }
}

private void Update() {
    CheckKeyPress();
}

private void CheckKeyPress() {
    if (chestHelperMessage.activeSelf) {
        CheckInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of code from my game that works for me:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) // you can check if the collider is a player but I did not in this instance
{
    HelperMessage.SetActive(true);
    canOpenChest = true;
}

void Update()
{
    if (canOpenChest && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        HelperMessage.SetActive(false); // set active to false because the chest is now open
        Destroy(gameObject); // instead of this play an animation or whatever and, you can also remove the collider from the chest
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    Text.SetActive(false);

    canPickup = false;      
}`
```

The answer by derHugo is technically right but I don't like IEnumerators so I never use them